# iOS8 how can I reduce the amount of system alert dialogs that I'm being asked?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, alert

Since upgrading to iOS8 I'm growing increasingly frustrated with the number of system dialogs that iOS randomly asks me.

- location in background
- set up family sharing
- another email address added to another device
- etc, etc, etc.

I find it really frustrating when I reach for my phone to take a picture and there's an alert dialogue sitting on top of the screen, it feels like I'm interacting with Windows 95.

**Is there a way to reduce amount of popups and alert dialogues that iOS8 asks the user?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These popups are the base of the privacy features of iOS. 
Also they are only displayed once if you allow the app to access the given service.

I should not bother much than that.